# Where does the random in Random Forests come from?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, ensemble-modeling

As the title says:

Where does the random in Random Forests come from?

Comment: Already explained in the Wikipedia article on random forests: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest#Tree_bagging, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest#From_bagging_to_random_forests.  I suggest you read standard references before asking -- it'll help you to ask a better question, or let you answer your own question.  There's little point in us duplicating material already available on standard resources (like Wikipedia).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each tree you randomly select from the variables that you can use to split tree nodes. Generally you randomly select 1/3 of the variables per tree.